# Rotate an SVG by 90 degrees on the command line

Tags: command-line, svg

I have an SVG that I'd like to rotate by 90 degrees counterclockwise on the command line.

With Inkscape 1.2.2, I tried

```
inkscape --actions "select-all;transform-rotate=90;export-filename:out.svg;export-do" input.svg
```

but that only gives

```
InkscapeApplication::parse_actions: could not find action for: transform-rotate=90
```

Any hints?

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `transform-rotate:90` (colon instead of equals?) you can also try `ObjectRotate(degrees:90)`

Comment: @YisroelTech Yep, that was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with the other parameters used (`export-filename:out.svg`) you should use a colon instead of an equals sign for the `transform-rotate:90`.

Try:
`inkscape --actions "select-all;transform-rotate:90;export-filename:out.svg;export-do" input.svg`

Comment: This doesn't rotate the canvas so you'll probably end up with a cropped image.